# Удаление файлов gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Использую плагин `gulp-watch`
Столкнулся с тем, что при удалении файла из рабочей директории приходиться так же удалять его и из папки сборки.
Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
watch('dev/**/*.{jpg,png}', function(event, cb) {
            gulp.start('img');
    }).on('unlink', function(file){
        var basename = null;
        var index = file.lastIndexOf('\\');
        basename = file.slice(index + 1);
        del('app/**/img/' + basename);
    });
```

Смущает только поиск имени файла, для этого я ищу первый `/` с конца строки и в `windows` это `lastIndexOf('\\')`.
Может есть способы сделать более универсально, что бы работало и на других платформах?

Comment: А зачем удалять файл из папки сборки? Ведь можно при запуске команды для сборки продакшн версии сперва очищать папку, а потом выполнять все остальные задачи. Чем мешает ненужный файл при разработке?

Comment: @YozhEzhi это верно, но уж больно я педонтичен. Незачем валяться ненужному хламу, даже в процессе разработки.